# How to merge two firebase observables?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

> I used the map and the flatMap Rxjs operatores to made Firebase relational Database.

I hade the following Firebase lists:

**INVITATION LIST**
[image]

**#####PLACES LIST#####**
[image]

I fetched the placeInvited info by the following way:

```
this.places = this.placesProvider.getMyInvitations()
.map(invitations => {
  return invitations.map(invitation => this.devicesProvider.getDevice(invitation.placeInvited))
})
.flatMap(fbojs =>{
  return Observable.combineLatest(fbojs)
});
```

And the code above is working well, The places List is fetched !.

```
{
 name:"Gmail place",
 owner:asdrvrat5....,
 .
 .
 .
}
```

But my problem is I Don't have access any more for the invitations list:

```
{
 guest:true,
 placeInvited:dasdjkd....,
 .
 .
 .
}
```

I tried to use the merge operator to fix this problem and my code be came:

```
this.invitations = this.placesProvider.getMyInvitations()
  .map((invitations:any) => {
    return invitations.map(invitation => {
      return merge(
        this.devicesProvider.getDevice(invitation.placeInvited),
        this.placesProvider.getInvitation(invitation.$key)
      );
    })
  })
  .flatMap(fbojs => {
    return Observable.combineLatest(fbojs);
  })
  .do(console.log)
```

But I fail.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: How should the two observables be connected to each other?

Comment: I need to merge it to be in one Object

Comment: @ritaj for example i need to bind the invitation.guest and the invitation.deleted in the html file. now i can bind the invitation.deleted but i can i bind the invitation.guest